# ssh login permission denied (public key) on windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, ssh, cloud

I'm trying to connect to my remote ovhcoud server but I can't connect (permission denied).
First of all I generated a public and private key thanks to putty gen.
While I put the private key (key.ppk) in the folder `C:\Users\toto\.ssh`
I don't know where the problem is

```
C:\Users\toto> ssh myinstance@ipaddr 
Permission denied(public key)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: This doesn't have to do with PowerShell (what happens from the command prompt?)

Comment: when i type the ssh command to login i have (permission denied)

Comment: I think the answer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1395962/is-it-possible-to-update-the-built-in-openssh-client-in-windows-10) will likely resolve your issue. I have had to update my putty client recently due to also getting authentication failures.